# Simplifying regex expression (L+M*)*

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

To simplify it, it seems that we can do $(L+M^*)^* = (L+M)^*$, but I also need to prove it.$(L+M)^* ⊆ (L+M^*)^*$ seems straight forward. However, $(L+M^*)^* ⊆ (L+M)^*$ is what I couldn't figure out. Should I use $ (L^*M^*)^*$ instead of $( L+M)^*$? If I use it and do induction on k, $ u ∈ (L+M^*)^*$ and u = (v1+m1)...(vk+mk); j = 1...k, vj ∈ L, and mj ∈ M*.

For k=1,   $v1⊆L ⊆ (L^*M^*)^*$ and $m1⊆M^* ⊆ (L^*M^*)^*$, $v1+m1⊆  (L^*M^*)^*$. How do I continue afterwards?

Comment: Try induction on the length of the string $x$. Let $L_1 = (L+M^\ast)^\ast$ and $L_2 = (L+M)^\ast$. Observe for $|x|=0 \implies x=\epsilon$ which belongs to both languages. 

Now assume for $x\in \{0,1\}^{k}, k\leq n$, $x\in L_1 \implies x\in L_2$. Now take a string $x\in L_1$ of length $n+1>0$. Then $x=yz$ where $y\in (L+M^\ast-\{\epsilon\})=\{L, M, M^2, ...\}, z\in L_1$ by definition. Since $z$ has at most $n$ characters, then $z\in L_2$ by induction. In addition, We can form $y$ from $(L+M)^\ast$, so $y\in L_2$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: @AspiringMat, I think I can't, I'm unfamiliar with those

Comment: Unfamiliar with what?

Answer (score 0):

Informally, $(L+M)^*$ represents any sequence made of $L$s and/or $M$s, you can't make it more general. $(L+M^*)^*$ of course includes $(L+M)^*$, but the latter cannot be a proper subset.

---

More rigorously,

$$L+M^*⊆(L+M)^*$$ so that

$$(L+M^*)^*⊆((L+M)^*)^*=(L+M)^*$$